# Nested sums in `Compile`

Tags: compile

in my code I face the necessity of using nested sums within `Compile[]`.
Unfortunately, nested sums cause a call to `MainEvaluate` as can be seen from the following trivial example:

```
cf1 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}}, 
  Sum[i + j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, m}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
cf2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}}, 
  Sum[i + Sum[j, {j, 1, m}], {i, 1, n}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[cf1]
CompilePrint[cf2]
```

While multi-dimensional sums are fully compilable (see the output of `CompilePrint[cf1]`), this is no longer the case for nested sums (see the output of `CompilePrint[cf2]`).

What are practical strategies for nested sums within `Compile[]` to avoid calls outside the compiler?

Comment: I am aware of this thread, though I think it is kind of different and the solution is not applicable to my case. I can't wrap around a `Total@Table[..]`. If this construct is used within a `Sum` one still has a `MainEvaluate` call.

Comment: Then just replace all the `Sum`s with `Total@Table[…]` or `Do[……]`. Notice this can be easily achieved with code generation technique: `sum[expr_, iter_] := Module[{k = 0.}, Do[k += expr, iter]; k];

cf4 = Hold@Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {m, _Integer}}, sum[i + sum[j, {j, 1, m}], {i, 1, n}],
       CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] //. DownValues@sum // 
   ReleaseHold;
CompilePrint@cf4`

Comment: Ok that might be a way. I think I once tried that and it was somewhat slower than just manually writing out the terms (which is of course not possible for every sum). But I need to check this again, and also try to use the hint from your comment. Thank you! [Edit]: Yeah, already with the trivial code from above, your code is like 4 orders of magnitude faster than if I replace all the `Sum`s with `Total@Table`.

Comment: Alternatively, I could also break the two nested sums in two multidimensional sums, but this is also extending the lines of code.

Comment: @DisplayName Just a side remark: It is a very bad idea to define compiled functions with `DetDelayed` (`:=`) as this recompiles the function each time it is called. I took the freedom to correct it in your post.

Comment: Here in the example yes, but if I have to change parameters in my code each time I run it, I think `SetDelayed` is the right choice.

Comment: So when I use a `Block` construct and have sth like `fun[b_]=Block[{a=a},...]` but only after I defined this line assign the variable `a` a value lets say `a=3` and then call e.g. `fun[3]`, change the value of `a` and call `fun[3]` again the function takes the new value of `a`. Does `fun` use `SetDelayed` if in the initial definition of the function there are yet symbolic definitions in the scoping strucutre of `Block`? Because if I define `fun` again with `Set` after I gave `a` a  value I can give `a` whatever number the result of `fun[3]` won't change after repeated runs.

Comment: This is also reflected in a compiled function, if I use the option `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`. If I define the compiled function with `Set` and followed by a `Block[{a=a},...]` then if `a` was still symbolic in that definition and I just assign it a value afterwards and execute the function there is call to `MainEvaluate`. But the result behaves as if I defined it with `SetDelayed`. Then if I call the compiled function again after assigning a value to `a`, the function is fully compiled and doesn't change its result upon changing `a` (unless I call the function code again).

Comment: Interesting, thank you for your hint!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Coming back to the issue with `SetDelayed` (`:=`). If you have a compiled function and need to call this compiled function with different sets of parameters many times (the parameters are initiliazed with a `Block` construct inside `Compile`) how would you do it? In principle, using `SetDelayed` does it correctly, but as you pointed out it is rather slow as it needs to compile the code anew. Another way which comes to my mind would be to use all parameters as arguments of the compiled function (which is kind of annoying for a huge set of parameters). Is there another way?

Comment: Submit the parameter as variable to the `CompiledFunction`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Yes, this is probably the only way to avoid re-compilation. With 10 or more parameters the argument block of the `CompiledFunction` will become very large, but if there is no other solution I will go for this solution.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Now I have the problem, that if I inline an external function with `With` into the compiled function, submission of the parameter as a variable doesn't seem to work anymore, if this parameter only appears in the inlined (external) function. How may I fix this?

Comment: @DisplayName Wrong post? ;) I don't get it. Can you give a (minimal) example?

Comment: I initially used `SetDelayed` in my compiled function, to change parameters whenever I ran the code. Then you recommended to submit the parameter as variables to the `CompiledFunction` to avoid extensive re-compiling of a function (using `Set` then to define the `CompiledFunction`). This worked and parameters were updated. However, now I inline an external function with `With`. The parameters that are contained in this external function don't seem to be updated anymore, even if I give them as variables to the `CompiledFunction` and change them there.

Comment: Ok, I think it still works, I just had screwed up the sequence of commands. Sry for that false alert.